# How to add an excluding rewrite (un-rewrite) condition for specific file types?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following simple rewrite, which I am taking a slightly different approach to rewriting site content.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The goal, is to rewrite all files and folders, everywhere, except if the file is of a particular type.

Traditionally, the following approaches are taken which are bit too relaxed for this endeavor :

**1. Exclude all files/folders that physically exist:**

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

**2. Exclude specific folders from rewrite**

```
RewriteRule ^somepath - [L]
```

**3. Rewrite only specific file types**

```
RewriteRule ^\.html index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

**4. Combination of #2 and file types**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ images/$1 [QSA,L]
```

What I am wondering is what rule do I insert to exclude (keeping the sample short):  jpg,bmp,png    from being rewritten to `controller.php` regardless of the subfolder they are located in.

## Pseudocode

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip rewriting jpg,bmp,png
RewriteRule ^[..something here..] - [NC,L]

# rewrite everything else
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.*\.extensiongoeshere
```

Comment: is there anyway to condense this so that `!.*\.ext` can be a list of extensions ?  I wouldn't deem myself an expert on rewrite, so I have no idea if your example is capable of handling multiple extensions on a single condition, or how

Comment: It's just a regex, so do it how regexs do it.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you  :)  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png|bmp)$`